# How do I generate an array of pairwise distances in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Say I have an array that represents a set of points:

```
x = [2, 5, 8, 33, 58]
```

How do I generate an array of all the pairwise distances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x = [2, 5, 8, 33, 58]
print x.collect {|n| x.collect {|i| (n-i).abs}}.flatten
```

I think that would do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really do want an array instead of a matrix, this is O(n^2/2) instead of O(n^2).

```
result=[]
x.each_index{|i| (i+1).upto(x.size-1){|j| result<<(x[i]-x[j]).abs}}
```

Comment: this is still O(n^2), but with half the number comparisons.  O(n!) is not what you mean anyway.

Comment: Oops - If 4! is 4*3*2*1, what is 4+3+2+1 called?

Comment: 1 + 2 + ... + n = n * (n-1) / 2

Comment: @grifaton, right, but is there a name for it?  The product of numbers from 1 to N is N factorial.  What do you call the sum of numbers from 1 to N?

Comment: Well n*(n+1)/2 is the nth triangular number - but there's no commonly-used name or symbol for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
x.map{|i| x.map{|j| (i-j).abs } }
```

gives

```
[[0, 3, 6, 31, 56],
 [3, 0, 3, 28, 53],
 [6, 3, 0, 25, 50],
 [31, 28, 25, 0, 25],
 [56, 53, 50, 25, 0]]
```

(format it like this by printing it with 'pp' instead of puts)

and

```
x.map{|i| x.map{|j| (i-j).abs } }.flatten
```

gives

```
[0, 3, 6, 31, 56, 3, 0, 3, 28, 53, 6, 3, 0, 25, 50, 31, 28, 25, 0, 25, 56, 53, 50, 25, 0]
```

if you really want an array